# Better collisions detection than CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios

My character is represented by an UIImageView with that is 30 by 30 points. The enemy is another image view that is 240 points wide and 45 points tall. It appease that CGRectIntersectsRect only determines a collision between the two rectangular boxes. But I'm looking for something with more detail.

I'm not using SpriteKit or Cocos2d or Box2d or chipmunk. Is there anything better than CGRectIntersectsRect for corner collision detection and collision detection from the left and right sides and how do I program it?

Comment: Short answer: you don't. Instead you DO use one of the frameworks you mention that are created to make these things easier for you...

Comment: I would even consider the above comment an answer haha